# Disable home button tapped while push notification popup displayed

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

When push notification popup is shown in app and tapped on home button then push notification popup will hide without taking any action (Allow/Don't Allow)
So, is there any way that without taking any action on push notification popup and when tapped on home button popup will not hide. Screen will remains same?

Thanks

Comment: This is system behavior.

Comment: I’m not sure what’s your goal but if you’re asking the user a mandatory question and you need a response then use UIAlerController without a cancel button

Comment: I don't think so its possible, because its native apple behaviour and you cant change it.

Comment: I got an app "Espncricinfo app" and same functionality is working in this app. @TaimoorSuleman

Comment: When push notification popup shown in our app and if user pressed home button then notification popup will disapper. So , i want that without taking any action on notification popup(Allow/DisAllow) popup will not disapper when tapped on device home button @zombie

Comment: ok let me install cricinfo.

Comment: Mam, Please recheck espn app. There are two types of notifcation alerts are there.
First is for Location Access and second is for notification.Home Button is disabled for Location Access Alert not for Notification Popup.

Comment: its a native behaviour , and is same for all users.

Answer (score 0):

Please check push notifications delegate methods.